# Passing FullCalendar date to my dialog box modal form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar and what I want is that the date clicked be passed to a dialog box modal form(asp.net mvc PartialView). This is my code right now:

```
 $calendar.fullCalendar({

        events: "/Home/CalendarData",
        dayClick: function (date) {
            $calendar.fullCalendar("renderEvent", { title: "on process", start: date}, true);

            $("#editDialog").html('')
            .load("/Home/About", function () {
                $("#editDialog").data("value", date).dialog("open");
            });
        }
    });
```

As you see i already tried passing a value to my dialog using data() function. Is there a way for my PartialView to access that data?

Comment: are you populating your entire Dialog with this value?

Comment: no , just one field. The Reservation Date field.

Comment: is #editDialog the entire dialog or a single controle?

Comment: editDialog is the <div> for the dialog. I don't know what you mean by single control but that's where i place my dialog. So i want that date variable passed to the dialog with partialview in it. is this possible?

Comment: Or is it possible to pass that date variable in to a ViewBag maybe? Thank you.

Comment: are you passing a single piece of data to the div (date) or an entire dialog box?

Comment: .load("Home/About") is passing in a partialview to the div which contains the <form>.

Comment: that makes sense, but then whatabout data("value", date). This seems to strip out a part of the dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to pass a json payload using the second parameter of the $.load

for example

```
$calendar.fullCalendar({
        events: "/Home/CalendarData",
        dayClick: function (date) {
            $calendar.fullCalendar("renderEvent", { title: "on process", start: date}, true);

           var payLoad = {
              ‘selectedDate’ : date
           };

            $("#editDialog").html('')
            .load("/Home/About", payLoad, function () {
                $("#editDialog").data("value", date).dialog("open");
            });
        }
    });
```

In the above example, we are creating a json object by the name of **payLoad** and passing it in via $.load method. Now you can define a variable by the name **selectedDate** on your controller action and capture the value