# Passing Fullcalendar Clicked Day to Modal Form (rails) (have fiddle)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

There was another question similar to this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053390/passing-fullcalendar-date-to-my-dialog-box-modal-form), but it didn't quite answer my question.

I am using Rails, and Fullcalendar for a booking app.  The functionality I am looking for is that when a user clicks on a day, it opens up a modal popup with a form to create a new booking.  I have this working -- but I want one step further.  I want the form select fields to prepopulate with the date that was clicked on the fullcalendar.

Also, relating to rails -- the form populates a lot of heavy html select menus.  Should I be targeting these select menus with jquery and trying to pass the values from fullcalendar there, or is there an easier way.

The form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @booking, class: "ui form segment" do |f| %>
              <p>
                <%= f.label 'start_time', 'Start Time:' %>
                <%= f.datetime_select :start_time, { minute_step: 15 } %>
              </p>
              <p>
                <%= f.label 'end_time', 'End Time:' %>
                <%= f.datetime_select :end_time, { minute_step: 15 } %>
              </p>
              <p>
                <%= f.label 'studio_id', 'Studio:' %>
                <%= f.collection_select(:studio_id, Studio.all, :id, :name) %>
              </p>
               <p>
                <%= f.label 'Title', 'Title' %>
                <%= f.text_field( :title)%>
              </p>
               <p>
                <%= f.label 'Engineer', 'Engineer' %>
                <%= f.collection_select( :engineer_id, Engineer.all, :id, :email)%>
              </p>

              <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: "ui large green button" %>
<% end %>
```

Which renders the long html you will see in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vgfwv/32/)

The default start time for the form is 'today' at a the most recent hour (10:59 yields 10:00).  It would be cool to override THIS to whatever data the fullcalendar is holding, itstead of targeting crazy li select etc.

Comment: once you start dealing with events in the browser, server side code won't help you. You will need to update date fields using javascript/jQuery using event handlers

Comment: Ah that makes sense... wishful thinking I suppose... how can I do that here though?  I try to save the date obj as a global variable (last clicked day) but I don't think it works outside of scope

Comment: for example your current alert is triggered from an event handler, parse the date (that you already have access to) to the fields that you want to change in that mouse event. Similarly do something with the submit event. The easy work was to get the data to the UI in the browser... now you will need quite a bit of UI code

Comment: Any good references for parsing jquery? I'm not too experienced in this

Comment: start with `val()` method to get/set values http://api.jquery.com/val/ The API has examples for every method

Comment: eh... don't I need to store the date in a variable? and then get the val of the variable?